# C# queries error

Tags: c#, sql-server, rdlc

I am c# beginner and hopefully get a help here.
I am not using SQL Server but just a query put in c# as shown below:

```
SqlCommand custcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT customer.customerid, warehouse.warehouseNo, warehouse.qty_goods, warehouse.qty_slack, warehouse.std_weight, (qty_goods+qty_slack)*std_weight/1000 AS Total 
FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN warehouse WHERE customer.customerid BETWEEN" + "textbox1.text" + "AND" + "textbox2.text", myconnection)
```

An error is shown "Incorrect syntax near WHERE"
Can anyone please comment and help?

Thank in advance

Comment: If you use a `SqlCommand` in your code, then you **are** using SQL Server ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BETWEEN" + "textbox1.text" + "AND" + "textbox2.text"
```

if you put 1 and 3 in textbox1 and textbox2 it will produce

```
BETWEEN1AND3
```

so here is a error

DO:

```
BETWEEN " + "textbox1.text" + " AND " + "textbox2.text"
```

Or better:

```
string.Format("SELECT customer.customerid, warehouse.warehouseNo, warehouse.qty_goods, warehouse.qty_slack, warehouse.std_weight, (qty_goods+qty_slack)*std_weight/1000 AS Total 
FROM Customer INNER JOIN warehouse WHERE customer.customerid BETWEEN {0} AND {1}", textbox1.Text,textbox2.Text)
```

using `String.Format` will prevent you from making such mistakes, because you see better what will be produced as query

Comment: oh this is amazing, your explanation is clear and I am just realise it.

By the way, another question,
(qty_goods+qty_slack)*std_weight/1000 AS Total
May u provide some guideline how to add column "Total" to rdlc report, and I have no idea how to pass the value to report.
I have done some research but I realise that most of it are done in one place by using Expression in report

Can u help? Sorry for my silly.

Comment: @user2901955 I supose you need to use some datasource for rdlc report so try expanding datasource

Answer (score 1):

After `INNER JOIN warehouse` you should add condition `ON` to link tables for example

```
INNER JOIN warehouse ON customer.<field> = warehouse.<field>
```

It is the reason of the error  "Incorrect syntax near WHERE" but also you should change WHERE statement according to the @wudzik's answer